# Сортировка двух векторов на месте

Tags: c++, алгоритм, сортировка, оптимизация, c++17

Есть два вектора `std::vector<int>`. Как отсортировать их оба так, чтобы результат был такой, как будто бы сортировался один вектор-конкатенация двух? Без использования 3 вектора/линейной памяти.

Пример:

```
a: 3, 1, 5

b: 2, 9, 3, 1
```

Результат:

```
a: 1, 1, 2

b: 3, 3, 5, 9
```

Comment: Если используется С++20, то можно воспользоваться std::views::join+std::sort.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117278/discussion-on-question-by-ueber-----).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Организуете доступ по индексу к виртуальному объединению

```
void put(idx, value)
   if (idx < len1)
       A[idx] = value
   else
       B[idx - len1] = value

int get(idx)
   return  (idx < len1)? A[idx] : B[idx - len1] ;
```

И применяете сортировку кучей, или вставками (медленно), или быструю (памяти log(n))

Comment: Надо свою сортировку писать или можно как-то это встроить в стандартный `std::sort`?

Comment: Если Вам надо владение  C++ продемонстрировать, то тут я грамотно не подскажу, а в целом - делаете класс, в котором описаны `::iterator begin`, end (и [] доступ по индексу, наверное) к объединению, и `std::sort` применяете. [некий пример](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5897319/how-to-use-stdsort-to-sort-an-array-in-c)

Comment: Автор вопроса хочет по максимуму сэкономить память. Вроде бы нет гарантий, что `std::sort` в процессе сортировки не выделяет доп. память?

Comment: @Джонни Кэтсвилл В ответе я из этих соображений HeapSort посоветовал в первую очередь. Про стандартный - да, гарантий нет, хотя наиболее вероятная имплементация - QuickSort c небольшой памятью

Answer (score 1):

### Предисловие

Можно создать свой итератор. Не нужно относится серьёзно к тому что получилось. Нормальный итератор лучше сделать шаблоном и конструировать от двух пар итераторов. Или лучше ввести ввести понятия [range и  view](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges) из C++ 20. Для них определена операции `views::join` и `views::concat`, которые объединяют диапазоны. Пример такого кода в конце ответа.

### Самодельный итератор

Пример будет минимальным, под конкретные типы. Начнём с определения класса итератора, вспомогательных функций и тестового кода. Ещё есть оператор для печати вектора, он опущен:

```
class Iterator {
public:
    Iterator(std::vector<int> &a1, std::vector<int> &a2, int i);

private:
    std::vector<int> *a1;
    std::vector<int> *a2;
    int i;
};

Iterator::Iterator(std::vector<int> &a1, std::vector<int> &a2, int i)
: a1(&a1), a2(&a2), i(i) {
}

Iterator begin(std::vector<int> &a1, std::vector<int> &a2) {
    return Iterator(a1, a2, 0);
} 

Iterator end(std::vector<int> &a1, std::vector<int> &a2) {
    return Iterator(a1, a2, a1.size() + a2.size());
} 

int main() {
    std::vector<int> a1 = {3, 1, 5};
    std::vector<int> a2 = {2, 9, 3, 1};

    std::cout << a1 << " | " << a2 << '\n';

    std::sort(begin(a1, a2), end(a1, a2));

    std::cout << a1 << " | " << a2 << '\n';
}
```

Конструктор принимает ссылки на вектора, чтобы не было соблазна передать `nullptr`. В теле класса хранятся указатели, чтобы итератор можно было копировать. Поле `i` - номер элемента на который указывает итератор.

Код не компилируется, ошибка указывает на отсутствие `operator !=`. Добавим его:

```
class Iterator {
    ...
    friend bool operator !=(const Iterator &it1, const Iterator &it2);
    ...
};

bool operator !=(const Iterator &it1, const Iterator &it2) {
    return it1.i != it2.i;
}
```

Следующая ошибка - нет `operator -`. Добавим его и ещё несколько штук:

```
    friend int operator -(const Iterator &it1, const Iterator &it2);
    friend Iterator operator +(const Iterator &it1, int i);
    friend Iterator operator -(const Iterator &it1, int i);
    friend bool operator ==(const Iterator &it1, const Iterator &it2);
    Iterator &operator ++();
```

Следующая ошибка интереснее: `std::iterator_traits<Iterator>` не содержит тип `value_type`. Читаем документацию по [iterator_traits](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits): нужно объявить пять типов в классе итератора:

```
    using difference_type = int;
    using value_type = int;
    using pointer = int *;
    using reference = int &;
    using iterator_category = std::random_access_iterator_tag;
```

Ещё ошибки и ещё операторы:

```
    int &operator *();
    friend bool operator <(const Iterator &it1, const Iterator &it2);
    Iterator &operator --();
```

`operator *` единственный интересный:

```
int &Iterator::operator *() {
    return (i < static_cast<int>(a1->size())) ? (*a1)[i] : (*a2)[i - a1->size()];
}
```

Готово. Код скомпилировался и отработал:

```
3, 1, 5 | 2, 9, 3, 1
1, 1, 2 | 3, 3, 5, 9
```

Программа целиком:

```
// g++ -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -std=c++17 sort_vectors.cpp

#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &os, const std::vector<int> &a) {
    bool first = true;
    for (int v : a) {
        if (first) {
            first = false;
        } else {
            os << ", ";
        }
        os << v;
    }
    return os;
}

class Iterator {
public:
    using difference_type = int;
    using value_type = int;
    using pointer = int *;
    using reference = int &;
    using iterator_category = std::random_access_iterator_tag;

    Iterator(std::vector<int> &a1, std::vector<int> &a2, int i);

    friend bool operator ==(const Iterator &it1, const Iterator &it2);
    friend bool operator !=(const Iterator &it1, const Iterator &it2);
    friend bool operator <(const Iterator &it1, const Iterator &it2);
    friend int operator -(const Iterator &it1, const Iterator &it2);
    friend Iterator operator +(const Iterator &it1, int i);
    friend Iterator operator -(const Iterator &it1, int i);
    Iterator &operator ++();
    Iterator &operator --();
    int &operator *();

private:
    std::vector<int> *a1;
    std::vector<int> *a2;
    int i;
};

Iterator::Iterator(std::vector<int> &a1, std::vector<int> &a2, int i)
: a1(&a1), a2(&a2), i(i) {
}

bool operator ==(const Iterator &it1, const Iterator &it2) {
    return it1.i == it2.i;
}

bool operator !=(const Iterator &it1, const Iterator &it2) {
    return it1.i != it2.i;
}

bool operator <(const Iterator &it1, const Iterator &it2) {
    return it1.i < it2.i;
}

int operator -(const Iterator &it1, const Iterator &it2) {
    return it1.i - it2.i;
}

Iterator operator +(const Iterator &it, int i) {
    return Iterator(*it.a1, *it.a2, it.i + i);
}

Iterator operator -(const Iterator &it, int i) {
    return Iterator(*it.a1, *it.a2, it.i - i);
}

Iterator &Iterator::operator ++() {
    ++i;
    return *this;
}

Iterator &Iterator::operator --() {
    --i;
    return *this;
}

int &Iterator::operator *() {
    return (i < static_cast<int>(a1->size())) ? (*a1)[i] : (*a2)[i - a1->size()];
}

Iterator begin(std::vector<int> &a1, std::vector<int> &a2) {
    return Iterator(a1, a2, 0);
} 

Iterator end(std::vector<int> &a1, std::vector<int> &a2) {
    return Iterator(a1, a2, a1.size() + a2.size());
} 

int main() {
    std::vector<int> a1 = {3, 1, 5};
    std::vector<int> a2 = {2, 9, 3, 1};

    std::cout << a1 << " | " << a2 << '\n';

    std::sort(begin(a1, a2), end(a1, a2));

    std::cout << a1 << " | " << a2 << '\n';
}
```

### Почти пример кода из C++ 20

Запустить компилятор с поддержкой C++ 20 ranges мне не удалось. Код ниже работает с библиотекой [ericniebler/range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) которая была прототипом `ranges` из стандарта. Сортировка вызывается косвенно через `ranges::sort`:

```
// g++ -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -std=c++14 -Irange-v3/include ranges.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <range/v3/all.hpp>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> a1 = {3, 1, 5};
    std::vector<int> a2 = {2, 9, 3, 1};

    std::cout << ranges::views::all(a1) << ranges::views::all(a2) << '\n';

    ranges::sort(ranges::views::concat(a1, a2));

    std::cout << ranges::views::all(a1) << ranges::views::all(a2) << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Столько усилий, а какой выигрыш (во времени и MAX RSS) по сравнению, скажем с сортировкой векторов по отдельности и последующим слиянием? (ну, слияние придется написать самому и оно потребует дополнительной памяти размером с короткий вектор)

Comment: Выигрыш в том что стали работать вообще все алгоритмы, которые не меняют размер контейнера, не только `sort`. Не будьте так серъёзны, это игрушка, упражнение в "compiler-driven development".

Comment: Да, упражнение в языкознании убедительное (я плюсанул)

Comment: Спасибо на добром слове!

Comment: Наверное ответ выйдет тогда слишком длинным, но не могли бы вы показать и то, как это будет работать с ranges в C++20? @StanislavVolodarskiy

Comment: Добавил. Намного длиннее ответ не стал.